# WinAPI to return Window Resizing Object size (This is the boarder around a window)

Tags: winapi

WinAPI to return Window Resizing Object size (This is the boarder around a window that allows you to resize the window). I just need the number of pixels it takes. (Under Windows 7, it looks like it is about 10 pixels.)

Also, what is the official name for this object?

I am coding in a language call PL/B and placing objects on their window. I am using GetWindowRect to get the window size, now I just need to adjust the size by the Window Resizing Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you're better off looking at GetClientRect and ClientToScreen, rather than trying to use GetWindowRect and trimming off the nonclient portions, but if you're dead set on doing that, try [GetSystemMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with SM_CXSIZEFRAME and SM_CYSIZEFRAME.